# laravel auth add a admin

Tags: laravel, authentication

Hi I am trying to follow the laravel multi auth example as seen here:
I am using laravel 5.6, I think dev marketer is using 5.2.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir2nAD9UDGg&t=1930s
So my admin controller is as below:

The problem is if I go to :  `localhost/site1/admin`
I get a error in the browser

> "This page isn’t working
>   localhost redirected you too many times.
>   Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

I guess as it says it is stuck in some kind of redirect loop???

If I comment out the constructor it goes to admins page without 
being logged in, which is obviously not good.

I also added a function to : handler.php is shown below :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //return view('auth/admin');
        return view('auth/admin');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.admin-login');
    }

    public function login( Request $request )
    {
        // validate form
        $this->validate( $request , [
            'email'     =>  'required|email',
            'password'  =>  'required|min:6'
        ]);

        // attempt login
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password])) {
            // if successful goto intended page
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }

        // unsuccessful - redirect.
        return redirect()->back()->withInput( $request->only('email','remember'));
    }
}
```

**Handler.php**

```
public function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthenticated' , 401 ]);
    }

    $guard = array_get( $exception->guards(),0);

    switch($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            $login='admin.login';  break;
        default:
            $login ='login'; break;
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route( $login ));
}
```

Also not sure if it's relevant or useful - but if I comment out the unauthenticated() function in handler.php it redirects to standard login/ instead of new admin login.
and keeping the function in gives me "The page isn't redirecting properly" in firefox

Answer (score 0):

think i solved it...
in handler I changed redirect to:

```
    case 'admin':
        if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('admin/dashboard');
        }
    break;
```

In RedirectIfAuthenticated:

```
    case 'admin':
        if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('admin/dashboard');
        }
    break;
```

In routes added Middleware :

```
Route::get('/'          , 'Auth\AdminLoginController@index')->name('admin.dashboard')->middleware('auth:admin');
```

In the admin controller I commented out the constructor:

```
//    public function __construct()
  //  {
    //    $this->middleware('auth:admin')->except('logout');
   // }
```

I changed:

```
return redirect()->guest(route( $login ));
```

To:

```
return redirect()->to( $login );
```

This seems to work - whether it's the "official" way to solve it I'm not sure!!